# Split a string in php with delimiters

Tags: php

So here's the scenario, I have the following string:

```
    Detroit 7 Chicago 13 (FINAL)
```

I want it to return an array as follows:

```
    array() { 
     ["T1_Name"]=>"Detroit" 
     ["T1_Score"]=>"7"
     ["T2_Name"]=>"Chicago" 
     ["T2_Score"]=>"13"
     ["Quarter"]=>"FINAL"
    }
```

The trick is it can't be space delimited because of cities with spaces in the name, also the scores may be one or two digits.

Comment: Is the format always string - int - string - int - string?

Comment: You could use this [regex](http://rubular.com/r/wgp88nwljn) with preg_match

Answer (score 1):

```
$subject = 'Detroit 7 Chicago 13 (FINAL)';
$matches = array();
if (preg_match('~^(.+) ([0-9]{1,2}) (.+) ([0-9]{1,2}) \((.+)\)$~i', $subject, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
    $result = array(
        'T1_Name'  => $matches[1],
        'T1_Score' => $matches[2],
        'T2_Name'  => $matches[3],
        'T2_Score' => $matches[4],
        'Quarter'  => $matches[5],
    );
}
var_dump($result);
```

Something like that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

**[PHP preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)**

Something like this perhaps?

```
preg_match('/([a-zA-Z\s]+?)[\s]+([\d]+)([a-zA-Z\s]+?)[\s]+([\d]+)[\s]+\(([\w]+)\)/', "Detroit 7 Chicago 13 (FINAL)", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```